# Python click test group commands cli

Tags: python-3.x, testing, command-line-interface, python-click

I have a cli that consists of a group that has 2 subgroups, and both of them share the same commands. How could I use CliRunner to invoke the commands for testing? (I need to mock some calls within the command)

```py
#main.py
@click.group()
def entry():
    pass

@entry.group()
def group1():
    pass

@entry.group()
def group2():
    pass


group1.add_command(subgroup)
group2.add_command(subgroup)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     entry()
```

```py
@click.group()
def subgroup():
    pass

@subgroup.command()
def sut():
    fun_to_be_mock()
```

The entry point is something like:

```
main.py group1 [arguments] subgroup sut [args for sut]
```

I have this weird pattern because all commands have 2 run modes that require different arguments. So depending on whether `group1` or `group2` the arguments are different.
I would like to test `sut` and mock something inside. I tried with CliRunner.invoke(), but I don’t know how to trigger such a command. I also tried using the `subprocess` module to run the command, but in that case I can't mock any function called inside?